# C++17 Pass reference to interface of templated class into sibling templated class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++17

Consider the following example:

```cpp
template <typename Consumer>
class ClassA
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    explicit ClassA(Args &&... args) :
        consumer_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        consumer_.consume();
    }

private:
    Consumer consumer_;
};

template <typename Consumer>
class ClassB
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    explicit ClassB(Args &&... args) :
        consumer_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        consumer_.consume();
    }

private:
    Consumer consumer_;
};

class ClassC
{
public:
    explicit ClassC(int val) :
        val_(val)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        std::cout << "ok " << val_ << std::endl;

    }

private:
    int val_;
};


void usage()
{
    ClassA<ClassB<ClassC>> composed_object(3);
    composed_object.consume();
}
```

It's a kind of templated bridge (or proxy? or strategy?) pattern, that I can easily compose and change implementation in compile time.

I try to avoid using of dynamic polymorphism due to performance reasons.

**So, the question**: How to allow ClassB to call some of ClassA methods?

The first thing that comes to my mind is to pass a reference of ClassA to ClassB. But there is a templated class chain and I don't want to change class chain usage.

I can rewrite ClassB as follows:

```cpp
template <typename Interface, typename Consumer>
class ClassB
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    explicit ClassB(Interface &interface, Args &&... args) :
        consumer_(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
        interface_(interface)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        consumer_.consume();
    }

private:
    Consumer consumer_;
    Interface &interface_;
};
```

So, it now takes an additional templated param of parent class Interface and a reference to parent in constructor.

But I have no idea how to specify templated param Interface in ClassA without change the chain usage.

To my mind it's a kind of template param infinity loop.

Comment: The simplest solutions might be polymorphism (add a base `Interface` type which `class A` inherits, and override the interface members) or if you only need to call a single entry point you could accept an `std::function` instead which wraps the call to the right member function. In any case, beware of copy and move, you need to make sure the handle to the outer object stays correct, which can be a challenge.

Comment: Reference data members should generally be avoided. Having a reference data member needlessly disables or breaks features like assignability. In the case of data members, it is often preferable to use pointers instead.

Comment: If you aren't telling an instance about another instance, then the instance doesn't know about the other instance, unless the other instance is themselves.  Classes know about two things; what you tell them, and their own identity (the implicit `this` pointer).  CRTP and (non-runtime polymorphic) inheritance could solve this.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  "Reference data members should generally be avoided" Yes, often that's at least a questionable approach, rather a real mistake often but I wouldn't state that a general rule. There are several use cases for some smarts or unique_ptr-forwarded interfaces for instance and there, the reference approach emphasizes your actual intentions (besides ownership clearness).

Comment: @Secundi I do not understand your last sentence.  References are aliases, and mechanical transformations can convert code using a `foo&` into code using a `foo*const` while blocking the pathologically surprising `operator=` vs constructor default behavior.  Any class or struct using both a reference and a non-reference member is extreme code smell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forget to say that it's a noncopyable classes. Yes, dynamic polymorphism is a natural solution, but it have a runtime cost. Is it possible to do it via static polymorphism?

Comment: try this [/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). from here [here](youtube.com/watch?v=vzDl0Q91MrM&t=173s)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont yes, CRTP possible can help. I know what is it. But how to integrate it to my current chain pattern? Make ClassA inherit ClassB ?

Comment: @512es Yes; instead of having a consumer, be the consumer.  Now the consumer who knows who they are consuming for can static cast themselves to reach their producer.

Comment: @512es Wrote it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to pass the producer to ClassB without passing it.  We can do this via the CRTP.

```
template <typename Consumer>
class ClassA:private Consumer
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    explicit ClassA(Args &&... args) :
        Consumer(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {

    }
    void say_hello() { std::cout << "hello!\n"; }
    void consume()
    {
        Consumer::consume();
    }
};
```

and change `ClassB` similarly.  Everything continues to work as is.  Now you want `ClassB` to find its producer.

```
template <template<class>class Producer, typename Consumer>
class ClassB:private Consumer
{
public:
    template<class... Args>
    explicit ClassB(Args &&... args) :
        Consumer(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        GetProducer().say_hello();
        Consumer::consume();
    }

private:
   Producer<ClassB>& GetProducer() { return *static_cast<Producer<ClassB>*>(this); }
   Producer<ClassB> const& GetProducer() const { return *static_cast<Producer<ClassB> const*>(this); }
};
```

here we tell `ClassB` who produces for it, and add a private method that gets their producer (assuming their producer uses the same inheritance composition strategy).

```
void usage()
{
    ClassA<ClassB<ClassA, ClassC>> composed_object(3);
    composed_object.consume();
}
```

here we pass in to `ClassB` how they are in turn going to be produced.

A constructed class knows a few things.  It knows its **arguments** to construction, and it also has an implicit `this` pointer.

Here we slip-stream the producer identity via CRTP and inheritance into the class, without having to pass it as an argument.

Using template aliases, you can even "skip" levels.  If you get it wrong, however, UB quickly results.

## A more meta approach can also be done.

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Us>
struct ztemplate {
  template<class...Ts>
  using result=Z<Us..., Ts...>;
};

template<class...> struct empty_t {};

template<class zProducer, class zConsumer, class...Ts>
class ClassA:
  public zConsumer::template result< ztemplate<ClassA, zProducer>, Ts...>
{
public:
    using Consumer = typename zConsumer::template result< ztemplate<ClassA, zProducer>, Ts... >;
    using Producer = typename zProducer::template result< ztemplate<ClassA>, zConsumer, Ts... >;
    template<class... Args>
    explicit ClassA(Args &&... args) :
        Consumer(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {

    }
    void say_hello() { std::cout << "hello!\n"; }
    void consume()
    {
        static_assert( std::is_same_v< typename Consumer::Producer, ClassA > );
        Consumer::consume();
    }
};

template <class zProducer, class zConsumer, class...Ts>
class ClassB:
  public zConsumer::template result< ztemplate<ClassB, zProducer>, Ts...>
{
public:
    using Consumer = typename zConsumer::template result< ztemplate<ClassB, zProducer>, Ts... >;
    using Producer = typename zProducer::template result< ztemplate<ClassB>, zConsumer, Ts... >;
    template<class... Args>
    explicit ClassB(Args &&... args) :
        Consumer(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        static_assert( std::is_same_v< typename Producer::Consumer, ClassB > );
        GetProducer().say_hello();
        Consumer::consume();
    }

private:
   Producer& GetProducer() { return *static_cast<Producer*>(this); }
   Producer const& GetProducer() const { return *static_cast<Producer const*>(this); }
};

template<class...>
class ClassC
{
public:
    explicit ClassC(int val) :
        val_(val)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        std::cout << "ok " << val_ << std::endl;

    }

private:
    int val_;
};

void usage()
{
    ClassA<ztemplate<empty_t>, ztemplate<ClassB>, ztemplate<ClassC>> composed_object(3);
    composed_object.consume();
}
```

but that probably goes too far.

Here every class in the chain is told about the structure of the entire chain "automatically".  (the static asserts are not universal, just debug checks that things work in this specific instance by not-UB).

To reduce compile time bloat, you can change the passed in `ClassC` as follows:

```
template<class Z> struct zAlways {
  template<class...>using result = Z;
};

void usage()
{
    ClassA<zAlways<empty_t>, ztemplate<ClassB>, zAlways<ClassC>> composed_object(3);
    composed_object.consume();
}
```

while removing `template<class...` from `ClassC`.

`ztemplate` is a pattern to pass a template as a class.  We use it here because you cannot write a template that takes as its first argument a template that takes as its first argument a template that takes as its first argument a template that...

`zAlways` obeys the pattern, that the real template is in `Foo::template result`.  Here we create a `ztemplate` that always returns a specific class.

But I [digress](https://godbolt.org/z/h9Yon1).